# Can you specify why ggsave function is not working?

Tags: ggplot2, ggsave

I have run a meta-analysis in metafor and created a forest plot.

I then tried to save this, using ggsave, as below:

```
ggsave("../Desktop/ASPD_META_ANALYSIS_LAPTOP/CVR.png")
```

But I get the error:

> Error in grDevices::dev.off() : QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open
> file '../Desktop/ASPD_META_ANALYSIS_LAPTOP/CVR.png'

Can someone please advise? I need a high res version of this image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`ggsave("./Desktop/ASPD_META_ANALYSIS_LAPTOP/CVR.png")`

with just one point `.` before `/Desktop`